# how to generate a link to a module controller in prestashop?

Tags: hyperlink, module, controller, prestashop

What's the exact way to generate a link to a module controller in prestashop? Also, how should really be named the controller's class and how the url params should mirror?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: this was an answer written in 2014, thus for prestashop 1.6: not sure if it still works.**

You will use an instance of the Link class. Generally you don't have to create one, just use `context->link` (ex. form a controller `$this->context-link`). The method is `getModuleLink()`, so:

```
$this->context->link->getModuleLink('module_folder_name','controller_name',array_of_params);
```

Beware the naming:

- Module folder name is exactly that..
- The controller must be in the right path, so for example module/controllers/front/controller.php
- The file name is the action, lowercase. The class name is ModuleFolder+Action+"ModuleFrontController"

So, for example:

**module dir:** orderattachment

**controller:** orderattachment/controllers/front/pdf.php

**controller class**:

```
class OrderAttachmentPdfModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
```

**link**:

```
$this->context->link->getModuleLink('orderattachments', 'pdf', [params..]);
```

Comment: How to specify a name of controller if you haven't controller? 
I have this: 
'$this->context->link->getModuleLink('wul4pay', 'payment', [], true) ' But I haven't a controller

Comment: Hi, 'payment' should be a module controller: are you sure it's not? Have you checked the module's folder? Also, generally, saying 'link to a controller' is quite the same as 'link to a page'. I mean, a controller exist for a page. In other words, if you don't have a controller, than you don't have a dedicated page, so the question is: what are you trying to link then?

Comment: And for admin link: $this->context->link->getAdminLink(ControllerName)

Comment: honestly, I don't know, I didn't tested 1.7 yet. But I guess you could easily find out by taking a look to the `Link` class. Just see if `Link::getModuleLink()` exists and if yes, take a look at the code. And/or eventually just try it.

Comment: I tried with 1.7.5 and this is where im stuck: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/12301

Comment: See the linked issue, its working if you follow the instructions precisely

Comment: @LucaReghellin: I needs to create a link like this `index.php?fc=module&module=MODULE_NAME&controller=CONTROLLER_NAME&cat[]=4&cat[]=6&type[]=1&type[]=2`.How can i generate using `getModuleLink`?

Comment: The naming from your code does not match the naming in your examples, so it is hard to follow. Moreover, for what version of Prestashop is this ?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way to create a link is to used an hyperlink in the view (template file) like the following:

```
 index.php?fc=module&module=MODULE_NAME&controller=CONTROLLER_NAME
```

By example, in a ecommerce for car repair shop, the customer have to set the car he/she will have during the next appointment (the module hooked in the right column).

If his/her vehicle do not exists, he/she needs to create a new one (the front controller page we want to call).

In my example, in the view, the link would be:

```
<a href="index.php?fc=module&module=vehiclefile&controller=newvehicle">{l s='Create a new vehicle' mod='vehicleFile'}</a>
```

**Note**: As mentioned by *Stratboy* in his answer, the naming convention is very important otherwise Prestashop won't be able to find the page. By example,

```
class VehicleFileNewVehicleModuleFrontControlle extends ModuleFrontController
```

is missing the "*r*" of "*controller*" in the class name and produce the following error:

[image]

**Note 2**: I used this most excellent tutorial (with a complete concrete example) to get started in my own project : http://nemops.com/creating-new-pages-in-prestashop/#.VjpH2LerRhF

Answer (score 0):

for Presta 8

```
public function Link::getModuleLink($module, $controller, array $params = array());
```

`$module` is the technical name of the module,

`$controller` is the controller file name (without ‘.php’),

`$params` is an array of variables to add in a customized route or simply as GET params.

The generated address handles automatically HTTP or HTTPS environments, with or without URL rewriting.

Example:

```php
<?php
Context::getContext()->link->getModuleLink('cheque', 'validation', array('idPayment' => 1337));
```

more details in Presta Docs -> https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/